# Get sequential file name from drawable folder

Tags: android, loops, drawable

I am writing an application where using 200+ images placed in drawable folder and all these files follow same naming convention say `thumb+X`

To read/display these files one way is to select every drawable file by follow `R.drawable.XXX`.

Is there any way to read these file name using loop or something else..so no matter how many file it will update in drawable, no need to touch source file then.

Any suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its Very Simple first you create an String Value Like.

```
String name= "R.drawable.thumb";
```

Now loop it like

```
for(int i=1;i<=200;i++){
    String resource = name + i;
    try {
        Class c = Drawable.class;
        Field idField = c.getDeclaredField(resource);
        int resourceDrwable = idField.getInt(idField);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Its Done.

Another Way is

```
int resourceId=Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier(pDrawableName, "drawable", "android");
```

Comment: its dangerous to use reflection on the R class, release build proguard optimizations will rename or just delete the constants. Besides, even if it may work, reflection is the most inefficient operation in Android.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following function to firstly get the resource id like this:

```
int resource_id=getResources().getIdentifier("thumb"+x, "drawable", getPackageName());
```

assuming you are inside an `Activity` (getResources / getPackageName are `Activity` methods)

and then if you need the `Drawable`

```
Drawable myDrawable=getResources().getDrawable (resource_id);
```

Mind that accessing a drawable by name is slower, you shouldn't abuse this method.